# Don't apply slash on blacklisted files

Tags: .htaccess

can you help me?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule ^favicon.ico images/favicon.ico [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# Redireciona
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(login.php/|login|login/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

This is my .htaccess file, I'm trying to don't apply **slash** for blacklisted files, as you can see, I'm trying to use **RewriteRule ^(login.php/|login|login/) - [L]** but still not working. Also, have no errors, only still not applying the blacklist

@edit: I've tried using **RewriteRule ^login([\w/-]+)(\?.*)?$ $1.php$2 [L]** but still not working too :/

What should I do?
Thanks